# What should I use columns for, and what should I use rows for in SQL?

Tags: database, database-design, sql, heroku

In SQL, what's the standard convention for what rows and columns should be used for? For instance, if I need to make a table of users and their data, which axis (rows or columns) should be the users labels and which axis should be the users data labels?

EDIT: The Free Heroku plan only allows a maximum of 10000 rows on the SQL table, so will it make a difference if I switch the table axises around and use a very large number of columns instead of rows?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I guarantee that your DBMS allows fewer columns than rows, so switching them wouldn't improve on that.  Plus-- you can't exactly switch them, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: This question is based off a complete misunderstanding of what a "table" is, in the database sense of the term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rows are used for **entities,** e.g. "users."

Columns are used for **fields,** e.g. "FirstName", "LastName."

Always.

So you're probably asking the wrong question.

The answer to the question you probably *should* be asking is "`Users` is one table, user data is in one or more additional tables joined to the `Users` table via Primary Key/Foreign Key relationships."

If you're trying to get around some limitation like the 10,000 rows of the free Heroku plan, switching the axes is going to cost you far, far more than just buying a data plan and doing it the right way.